# Does CameraSource.stop() require to be called from UI Thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, camera, barcode, google-vision

I am working on an android app that uses Google Barcode Scanner API from Mobile Vision. The purpose of app is to detect barcode and then take some action based on the data associated with barcode.

As soon as first barcode is detected, I want to stop the camera source so that the detection shouldn't continue. When I try to execute `cameraSource.stop()` inside `receiveDetections(Detector.Detections<Barcode> detections)` callback, the thread gets blocked and there is a lot of log output in logcat. Since this callback is not executed in UI thread, UI remains unblocked. I tried executing `cameraSource.stop()` in UI thread and it worked fine.

I have tried calling `cameraSource.start()` from UI thread as well as another thread and both work fine.

Now I couldn't find it anywhere in the documentation that interactions with cameraSource should be from UI thread or worker thread. I couldn't figure out the logic for why this would fail when called from another thread.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not necessary to call CameraSource.stop() from the UI thread, but due to an implementation detail it should not be called from the thread that executes receiveDetections.  The stop() code waits for this thread to finish, so calling it this way would create a deadlock.

Comment: Thanks for the response, it makes it more clear. I also had a look at `CameraSource`'s source [here](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-vision). But wouldn't it make more sense if instead of blocking the thread, the request is queued to the same thread that handles `receiveDetection()`? I don't really want to use flags to stop processing detected barcodes once first one is detected. Also if `stop()` is called from another thread, detector would continue to detect unnecessarily till the time stop() is actually executed.

Comment: The intent was to enforce that there was only one thread ever executing the detections from CameraSource.  Without joining the thread as the code does now, it would have been possible for clients to start and stop on CameraSource many times, sometimes resulting in multiple threads executing the detections simultaneously.  The thread will stop ASAP because it is marked as inactive before the join attempt.